# htaccess rewrite only when there is a query

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble with an rewrite rule im creating a small website for a friend the website has basic profile pages for his employees and im looking for a way to create the links into a facebook style link.

I currently have

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /staff_profile.php?staff=$1 [L]
```

Which redirects all pages to staff_profile.php, i need it to redirect only when the link is entered as http://example.com/j.smith which will redirect to john smiths page,

but when http://example.com/WhatEverPage.php is accessed i need it to show that page not staff_profile.php

Comment: It depends on whenever `WhatEverPage.php` is a real file or if you redirect the other request to another `.php` file. If the `WhatEverPage.php` exists then look at the answer of _anubhava_ otherwise you could look at `RewriteCond` or create multiple `RewriteRule`s in the order they should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /staff_profile.php?staff=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will skip above `RewriteRule` if request if for a valid file/dir.